# Express api + React can't use POST

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router, axios, babeljs

I'm just learning React so I'm a bit confused, I'm having trouble connecting to the backend of my script, I'm getting 404 errors in the console. The ones that came with this work fine, only the custom ones I make seem to break.

Also the forwarding URL is correct, I can use `GET` just not `POST`

I'm using https://github.com/tomlovesgithub/FullstackMERNTDDTutorial/

*router.js* **backend**

```
router.post("/processLogin", (req, res) => { console.log('hello 1') });
```

*index.jsx* **frontend** *I changed the files to .jsx*

```
axios.get(`${PORT}/processLogin`, { content: 'hi' }) .then(function (response) { console.log(response); }) .catch(function (error) { console.log(error); });
```

*console*

```
xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:3001/processLogin 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the console that you are making a `GET` request, but you only define a route that allows `POST` requests. You need to change your axios call to

```
axios.post(/*...*/)
```

You could also change your Node.js route to accept `GET` requests via `router.get()` or `router.all()`, but considering it looks like you are doing a login request, you would not want to do that.